# An extra blank line is being printed while executing a for loop for integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
for i in range(1,int(input())+1):
    print(((10**i-1)//9)**2)
```

An extra blank line is being printed in the for loop.

I've tried taking help from different websites.
Current output is:

```
1
121
12321
1234321
123454321
--here the extra line is being printed--
```

The expected output would be:

```
1
121
12321
1234321
123454321
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Please make a [mre]. Probably the problem is in another part of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Thats how `print` works. It prints the string representation of its argument(s) followed by `end` which is a newline by default. Thats why your output is not all on the same line to begin with.

You can manually specify `end` like this:

```
for i in range(1,int(input())+1):
    print(((10**i-1)//9)**2, end='')
```

but then everything will be on the same line. The workaround is to print the newlines separately.

```
for i in range(1,int(input())+1):
    print()
    print(((10**i-1)//9)**2, end='')
```

Here the newline is being printed before the string which prevents there being a trailing one. However there will be a leading newline instead. But that can be taken care of by not calling `print()` on the first iteration of the loop.

```
for i in range(1,int(input())+1):
    if i != 0:
        print()
    print(((10**i-1)//9)**2, end='')
```

Comment: Since you are testing for equality here and not identity, you should use `!=` instead of `is not`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the op wants newlines between the integers but not at the end, a concise way to express this is to build the target string using `join` and then print that without a newline.

```
n = int(input()) + 1
text = '\n'.join([ str(((10**i-1)//9)**2) for i in range(1,n) ])
print(text, end='')
```

The trouble with this approach is that you are constructing the whole text before printing. But this should be suitable for small lists.

an even shorter alternative is to use the arg `sep` as well as `end`.

```
print(*[ str(((10**i-1)//9)**2) for i in range(1,n) ], sep='\n', end='')
```